# onclick submit one of two same form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I included one file (containing a form) two times in php file.I want to submit one form with onclick function.
both forms are same.
i wrote onclick function
document.formname.submit();

I want to do somthing like this
    document.this.form.submit();
please give some solution.

Answer (score 1):

your forms should be something like this

```
   <form name="form1">
   ......
   <input type="submit" value="this submits form1">
   </form>


   <form name="form2">
   ......
   <input type="submit" value="this submits form2">
   </form>
```

Not like this:

```
   <form name="form1">
   ......
   <input type="submit" value="this submits form1">

   <form name="form2">
   ......
   <input type="submit" value="this submits form2">
   </form>
   </form>
```

You can not put one form into another.

Comment: <form name="form1">
   ......
   <a href="#" onclick="document.form1.submit();">submit</a>
   </form>


   <form name="form1">
   ......
   <a href="#" onclick="document.form1.submit();">submit</a>
   </form>

both forms are same i want something like this:
<a href="#" onclick="document.this.submit();">submit</a>

Answer (score 1):

with a button inside the form, you can do

```
$('form input[type="button"]').click(function ()
{
    $(this.form).submit();
})
```

**edit**

ok, so per OP's comment, it's anchors, not inputs:

```
$('form a').click(function ()
{
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
})
```

Comment: that'd need `return false` to prevent double-submission, and wouldn't need the handler in the first place.

Comment: I am using a link to submit a form not submit button.
<form name="form1">  ...... <a href="#" onclick="document.form1.submit();">submit</a>  </form>  <form name="form1">  ...... <a href="#" onclick="document.form1.submit();">submit</a>  </form> both forms are same i want something like this: <a href="#" onclick="document.this.submit();">submit</a>

Comment: @uwillneverknow: that's not wise.  semantic web?  <a>'s are not meant for that, *and* you're inflicting unnecessary work, as you can see now.  that said, see edited answer.